# Fields with an overlap between logic and algebra?

Tags: abstract-algebra, logic, soft-question, big-picture

I was curious if there is any field of study that uses both logic and algebra. To clarify, logic and analysis overlap in areas like descriptive set theory, and there are a lot of logic ideas in areas like topology. But I can't seem to think of any analogous relationships between logic and algebra. I'd appreciate any insight. Thanks

Comment: Model theory of fields is a 'large' active area of research in model theory.

Comment: Its not necessarily what you are asking; but Boolean Algebra follows the syntax of both.

Comment: Universal Algebra is certainly such an overlap

Comment: If you want to get a little more specific you can check out o-minimality theory https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/O-minimal_theory

Comment: Generalizing from Boolean Algebra are [Lindenbaum algebras](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lindenbaum%E2%80%93Tarski_algebra).  You can also indirectly use the relationships between topology and algebra to establish relationships between logic and algebra. At a much more advanced level, there's topos theory which links topology and algebraic geometry with logic and set theory as covered in [Sheaves in Geometry and Logic](http://www.springer.com/us/book/9780387977102) and many other places.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One such a field is the theory of [automata](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automata_theory) and [regular languages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_language).

I just state here a few results, with links to wikipedia for the definitions, to convince you that algebra and logic really help proving deep theorems in automata theory. There are many more, but unfortunately, most of these research level results are not treated in basic books on automata theory.

**Algebra**.

Thm 1 (consequence of Kleene 1956). A language is [*regular*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_language) if and only if its [*syntactic monoid*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_monoid) is *finite*.

Thm 2 (Schützenberger 1965). A language is [*star-free*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star-free_language) if and only if its [*syntactic monoid*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_monoid) is finite and [*aperiodic*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aperiodic_semigroup).

**Logic**

Thm 3 (Büchi 1960). A language is [*regular*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_language) if and only if its definable in [*monadic second order*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monadic_second-order_logic).

Thm 4 (McNaughton 1971). A language is [*star-free*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star-free_language) if and only if it is [*first order*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-order_logic) definable.

Thm 5 (Kamp 1968). A language is [*star-free*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star-free_language) if and only if it is definable in [*linear temporal logic*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_temporal_logic).

I would also recommend to read the French entries on Wikipedia for 
[Langage rationnel](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Langage_rationnel),
[Monoïde syntaxique](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mono%C3%AFde_syntaxique),
[Langage sans étoile](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Langage_sans_%C3%A9toile),
[Logique monadique du second ordre](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logique_monadique_du_second_ordre),
that are, for some reason, for detailed than their respective English versions.